# How to position divs correctly

Tags: css, css-position

I have 3 divs, main, right and left. The main div contains the right and left div and I want to align the right and left div side by side. I have read few posts here but have not been able to get the desired results.

https://jsbin.com/lagikaxiwe/edit?html,css,output

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#main-content {
  background-color: bisque;
  height: 100%;
}

div#right-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

div#left-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 35%);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 666px;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="right-content">
  </div>
  <div id="left-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @Paulie_D, thank you for the link. Still learning CSS so sticking to old ideas .

Comment: I did not put the code in the snippet because it does not show the entire thing.

Comment: Then you need to edit your question and include a [mcve], otherwise your question will be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method nowadays to use `display: flex` on the container. Have a look at the settings in my snippet - I erased a lot of the other settings, which are not necessary...

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

div#main-content {
  background-color: bisque;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

div#right-content {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

div#left-content {
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00aeef;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
  <div id="right-content">
  </div>
  <div id="left-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is flex compatible with IE? I have to make sure it works across all browsers.

Comment: depends on the version - from 11 on, yes. see http://www.caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 2):

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div#main-content {
      background-color: bisque;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
}

div#right-content {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

div#left-content {
  width: calc(100% - 35%);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00aeef;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use `display:inline-block` to align the left and right divs 
side by side and add the necessary widths to add up to 100% of the parent width. Be sure to use `font-size:0` on the parent to eliminate the white space between the left and right divs so they sit next to each other correctly.

Be sure to assign font-sizes to your left and right content so your content actually shows up!

This method is largely backwards compatible with all browsers.

```
div#main-content{
    font-size:0;
}

div#left-content{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:65%;
}

div#right-content{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:35%;
}
```